# Btrfs snapshot space and time overhead

Tags: snapshot, btrfs

Using [btrfs-snapshot-rotation](https://github.com/mmehnert/btrfs-snapshot-rotation), I've setup a system to rotate snapshots so that it always has snapshots of:

- Each of the the last 24 hours
- Each of the last 30 days
- Each of the last 12 months.

This system deletes old snapshots, but I'm wondering if this is necessary, and if I could just store hourly snapshots of the last 12 months - 8640 snapshots.

Will doing so result in:

- worse performance (for filesystem I/O, not for listing the snapshot folder!)
- more used space?

My guess is that, since btrfs is CoW, the performance will be the same, since the system will always have to copy changed blocks - it doesn't matter if there's 1 or 1000 snapshots.
I'm not so sure about the used space, though. Is there a way to verify this?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping old snapshots will definitely use **more disk space**. The amount depends on how many of your files change between snapshots.

There should be **no notable performance change** for the rest of the filesystem, as long as you have a reasonable fraction of free space and don't run into fragmentation problems.

We use [snapper](http://snapper.io/) in production, which keeps on the order of 1000 snapshots around. They take about the same amount of space as the normal filesystem for our usage.